# Delete Files and Folders Issue

Tags: java, file, websphere, directory, icefaces

My project is a Web project built using three technologies :

1. Icefaces for presentation layer.
2. Spring for business layer.
3. Hibernate for data access layer.

My Project deployed on WebSphere 6.1 and the user can upload files, I use ice:inputFile component to handle the upload process...

**The first issue is:**

When the upload process finished i expect to find the uploaded file under the following path : myWebProjectRoot/upload/"sessionId"/fileName.ext

where the "sessionId" is a folder named with the current session id and the fileName.ex is the file uploaded by the user...

But  what i found is : the folder "sessionId" did not created and the file is stored directly on the upload folder..

My Configuration is like the configuration of the component-showcase of icefaces library which i deployed it on my server and it create the sessionId directory successfully....

i don't know what to do.. please help me...

**The second Issue is :**

When the session expired I expect the sessionId folder will be deleted, i modified the code of component-showcase in the class *InputFileSessionCleaner* and make it delete the folder and it's children recursevly form bottm to up, but some time i face the current problem :

Some files can not be deleted using my code -may be they are used by another process-, thus the folder will not be deleted because one of its children didn't deleted. so what to do in this case ... ?

There is an idea in my mind, which is: 
Is there any way to create a process running at the background in the server-side: this process check the upload directory and if it founds any file created from at least 60 minutes -which is my session time out period specified in web.xml- this process will delete this file....

any one can help me.. every help will be appriciated .....

Comment: These are two separate questions.  you are more likely to get answers to your questions if you break it up into two questions.

Comment: Your first question has been answered here: [Stack Overflow question # 1447029](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447029/change-the-upload-directory-path-for-an-iceinputfile-component)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question:

WebSphere has a facility for creating worker threads and arranging for them to be initiated according to a schedule. This approach is fully supported in WebSphere - you don't violate any Java EE restrictions on thread creation by using it.

Search for Aysynchronous Beans in your WebSphere documentation.

There are a couple of flavours of this capability in WebSphere one of which is a generally standardised form that you may also find in other vendors App Servers. Some description is given here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/specification/j-commonj-sdowmt/index.html