# Change the upload directory path for an ice:inputFile component

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, icefaces

I've noticed that the ice:inputFile component will only upload files to the directory $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/MyAppName/upload/. I want this directory to be dependent on the user initials for the current user (i.e. user with initials abc wants to upload a file, the file goes to $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/MyAppName/upload/abc/). How can I dynamically set this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set the property uploadDirectory on the component, as such:

```
<ice:inputFile file="#{Bean.file}" uploadDirectory="./upload/#{Bean.userInitials}/"/>
```

This property is (currently) not mentioned in the JavaDoc for this component on the [ICEFaces](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_5_1/javadocs/components/api/com/icesoft/faces/component/inputfile/InputFile.html) site.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the reference guide
http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_8_2/htmlguide/devguide/references5.html

*web.xml* file:

To specify the directory location where uploaded files are stored, the following parameter is used:

```
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadDirectory</param-name>

<param-value>youruploaddirectory</param-value>
```

This parameter works in conjunction with the ice:inputFile component attribute "**uniqueFolder**" with four possible combinations as illustrated below:

```
                           **com.icesoft.faces.uploadDirectory**

                                   Set                                 Not Set

  **uniqueFolder**

   True           /app-context/uploadDirectory/sessionid/     /app-context/sessionid/

   False          /app-context/uploadDirectory/           /app-context/
```

Note:    The default upload directory specified via the configuration parameters above can be overridden on a per-instance basis via the uploadDirectory and uploadDirectoryAbsolute attributes on the ice:inputFile component.

Hope this helps!